# piping files to out-printer - powershell

Tags: powershell, printing

Got this script running. Nearly completed my mission to print attachments from it that land in a specific subfolder of outlook

```
    $OutputFolder = 'C:\tests';

$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application; 
$olFolderInbox = 6;
$ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI"); 
$inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox);
$inbox.Folders `
    | ? Name -eq 'colour' `
    | % Items `
    | % Attachments `
    | % {
        $OutputFileName = Join-Path -Path $OutputFolder -ChildPath $_.FileName;
        if (Test-Path $OutputFileName) {
            $FileDirectoryName = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($OutputFileName);
            $FileNameWithoutExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($OutputFileName);
            $FileExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($OutputFileName);

            for ($i = 2; Test-Path $OutputFileName; $i++) {
                $OutputFileName = "{0} ({1}){2}" -f (Join-Path -Path $FileDirectoryName -ChildPath $FileNameWithoutExtension), $i, $FileExtension;
            }
        }
        Write-Host $OutputFileName;
        $_.SaveAsFile($OutputFileName)
    }

Remove-Item -Path C:\tests\*.jpg

Dir C:\tests\ | Out-Printer -name xerox-b8
Remove-Item -Path C:\tests\*.*
```

when i try to pipe the objects to print i am getting XML printing out, or just the directory contents

I have tried:

```
select-object (wrong)
get-childitem (wrong)
DIR C:\tests\*.* (only returns directory listing printout)
```

These either return a load of XML rubbish or just a directory listing,

How can i pipe the contents of a folder to a printer using powershell, surely this can be done

Comment: What exactly do you want to get printed? Only the file names?

Comment: Please specify, in an example, exactly how you want the output to look... that has weight on the solution you're asking for.

Comment: This would be a load of office documents and PDF's.